# aMy jquery script does not work in ie 8, how to get around it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm trying to run a script in ie 8 but that does not work. The script works as follows:

1. I load an array `results` of divs with `$post`. Each div has a class `yearSOMEYEAR`, e.g., `year2012`, `year2013`,...
2. I want to distribute these divs in my page taking into account the numerical part `SOMEYEAR` of `yearSOMEYEAR`. For this I have some divs in my page with the id `gb_hidden_YEAR`..
3. To do the classification I call the function `classify()` as follows:

   ```
    for(i=1; i<results.length; i++){
       classify(results[i]);
           }
   ```
4. The function `classify` is below:

   ```
   function classify(seminar){

       $mydiv=$(seminar);

       var year=$mydiv.attr("class").replace(/[a-z]+/, '');

       $("#gb_hidden_"+year).append(seminar);

     }
   ```

This shoud do exactly what I want.

This works fine with chrome or firefox however that does not with ie 8?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: you have extra parentheses, change the code to `var year=$mydiv.attr("class").replace(/[a-z]+/, '');`

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? (testing in IE8, on MS website - `$("body").attr('class').replace(/[a-z]+/, '');` gives correctly `"02 plugin"`

Comment: The two extra pairs of parentheses are unnecessary but they won't affect the output.

Comment: @AminJafari and I've deleted and posted another comment before you notified me about your first comment, now we are on a time warp.

Comment: Ah, the snippet starts to make sense without all these parentheses.

Comment: The output of year with ie is "undefined"..

Comment: @PtF How do you check that? I think it is very unlikely `year` remains undefined. I think this is more likely to be a scope issue.

Comment: Are you by any chance running your code not inside `$(document).ready` block? Also - what is value of `seminar`? If it's an id selector - are you sure there is only one such element on the page?

Comment: Well, the issue is hard to debug if we don't see it first hand. Try to put some of your HTML and enough of your jQuery code to reproduce the issue into an isolated test case (e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/), see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for guidance.

Comment: Well, I guess it is not a scope issue for it works fine with chrome and the same about the id selectors..I'll try to add some more information..

Comment: Debug and figure out what part is not working. `console.log` is your friend. Is it reading the class right? Is it doing the reg exp right? Is it finding the element. ETC.

Comment: Well I did that and it does not work because the var `year` is not defined at least in ie 8..I don't know what else to do..

Comment: `console.log(mydiv.length);console.log($mydiv.attr("class"));` Do you get what you expect?

Comment: it says undefined on both commands..

Comment: UM, length should NOT return undefined.

Answer (score 0):

After a whole day trying to solve the problem I finally figured out what was wrong.

Thas was a suitable detail in my php code. I pass the variable `yearSOMEYEAR` from php to jquery with a span class as follows:

```
 "<span class='year".$row[i]."'>..."
```

The problem was that it was missing the closing tag `</span>`.

It sounds chrome deals nice with it whereas for ie 8 that is a chaos.